# Using fixtures with Stripe CLI

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to test my API behaviour by triggering some specific requests using [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli).

For example:

`stripe trigger customer.subscription.deleted # with some fixture here`

There is a fixtures command documented as a feature but I do not know how to use it. The documentation says:

> The fixtures command lets you run a json file as a series of API
>   requests. This can be useful for things like filling data, executing
>   specific flows, or testing API behavior.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/wiki/fixtures-command

How do I load fixtures into the CLI?

Answer (score 11):

The first step is to create a JSON file with the fixtures in it. The documentation you linked to gives one such example, but it may make it easier for you to get started if you:

- Find the closest available trigger to what you want to do
- Locate the corresponding fixture file [in the repo](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/tree/master/pkg/fixtures/triggers)
- Modify it to suit your needs

You can then execute the fixture with `stripe fixtures name_of_your_fixture_file.json`

You can look up available triggers in the [trigger documentation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/wiki/trigger-command). Remember that fixtures are just going to make a series of API requests, with each object in the `fixtures` array representing one API call, so you can do anything specified in the [API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api).

Comment: The documentation on the fixtures structure is useful too: https://stripe.com/docs/cli/fixtures