# How to emulate stripe requires capture event for webhooks?

Tags: go, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment-gateway

I am building a little Golang application that needs to perform a two-step payment using Stripe Checkout.

To know when to capture the payment, I use the Stripe Webhook API. I created a little endpoint waiting for an event `payment_intent.succeeded`. From which I get the `payment_intent.status` supposed to be at `"requires_capture"`.

Stripe provides some testing environment to trigger webhook via its Stripe CLI unfortunately, something like `stripe trigger payment_intent.requires_capture` is not supported (I'm using Stripe CLI v1.17.0).

I want to know if there is a way for me to trigger such an event using *preferably* Stripe tooling (but if there are other ways it's fine also) to test the capture workflow of my system.

### what I tried

I pretty much followed Stripe webhook testing documentation :

```bash
$ stripe login
$ stripe listen --forward-to localhost:2121/webhook
```

On another terminal pan, I did :

```bash
stripe trigger payment_intent.requires_capture
The event ‘payment_intent.requires_capture’ is not supported by the Stripe CLI.
```

So when I trigger `payment_intent.succeeded` instead, I got a `payment_intent.status` to `suceeded` instead of `requires_capture` that I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripe trigger` only accept the event type, which `payment_intent.succeeded` is valid. You can see the full list of events type at https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types.

You want to trigger *a custom fixture* of `payment_intent.succeeded` type. The easiest way is:

```
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded --edit
```

It will open up a json file. You can modify it and add `"capture_method": "manual",` in its param, then save the file to trigger your custom event.

You can modify a lot more of other parameters by creating your own fixture files, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60269842/3631795.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly ! I know now that I have to listen to `payment_intent.amount_capturable_updated` to get the `requires_status` from `payment_intent.succeeded`